# XCode Cache Tutorial

Tags: iphone, xcode, caching

Hey, I am trying to cache info on my IPhone App, but don't even know where to get started, I would to just cache a string (ex: 123123-12313123-1231231-123123), so when the user comes back it will remember it.

Is there a tutorial I can follow some where or could someone provide me some code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setString:@"123123123" forKey:@"myKey"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Later, when you wish to retrieve this object:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myString = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"myKey"];
```

You'll, of course, want to manage the keys properly, etc.